# This product requires Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: 2013, installation, prerequisites

I already Installed *Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5* in **Windows Server 2012  Release Candidate Data Center** using Features.
but When i started to install **SharePoint 2013** then it gives following error.

> Setup is unable to proceed due to the following error(s): This product
>   requires Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5

if I am trying to reinstall then it show that its already installed.

any solution for this error..?

Answer (score 21):

As mentioned by @jubblerbug, this can occur if you already have .NET Framework 4.6 installed before SharePoint 2013 (e.g. if you installed Visual Studio 2015 first). I couldn't use Microsoft's workaround as the option to remove .NET Framework 4.5 was disabled, and the ability to uninstall the .NET 4.6 update wasn't there either. So I used [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to examine what setup.exe was doing and work out the least invasive way to get around the issue.

**WARNING: This method is completely unsupported and should be used on development environments only.** Wait for Microsoft to correct the issue before applying to Staging or Production environments.

1. Run regedit.exe as administrator
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4`
3. Right-click the `v4` node, click Export, and save the export file somewhere safe - you will need it later
4. Right-click the `v4` node and click Permissions
5. Click Advanced
6. Change the Owner to your administrator account, tick "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects", and click OK
7. Go through each node under `v4` and:

   1. Right-click the node and click Permissions
   2. Set your administrator account to have Full Control and click OK
   3. Change any `Version` value you find from 4.6.*x* to 4.5.*x* (I used 4.5.51209)
8. Run setup for SharePoint 2013 until you see the "Run Configuration Wizard" screen
9. Untick the option to run the configuration wizard and click Close
10. Find the exported .reg file from earlier and double-click it
11. Confirm Yes that you want to import it back to the registry
12. Reboot and continue with your installation process

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.  Still getting the same error. Just spotted below that MS have released a work-around for this problem. Will check this out.

Comment: I used this to reinstall Office Web Apps 2013 after dot.net 4.7 had been installed.  Worked perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Microsoft released Hotfix for the issue. Please check the below link

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/09/14/sharepoint-2013-installer-now-supports-net-framework-4-6-and-above/

KB 3087184 link for download https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3087184

Hope it helps someone

Comment: This should be marked as an answer, as official solution while other answers suggests some hacks :) Tried and it worked for me on Server 2012 R2 with Updates clean install - though it looks like that it even didn't have .NET 4.6...

Answer (score 6):

The solution that worked for me:

1. Open Windows Update
2. View update history
3. Find the **KB** number in "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 for Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64 (*KB3102467*)"
   [image]
4. Open "Program and Features"
5. Search for the **KB** (*KB3102467*) and uninstall it
6. Now continue the installation of SharePoint

Comment: Worked for me, but the update didn't have such descriptive name. It was just "Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB3102467)"

Answer (score 5):

I also ran into this trouble spot one day when I was installing SharePoint 2013 for a client.

```
Setup is unable to proceed due to the following error(s): This product requires Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5
```

So you need to check which version of .NET framework is installed on the server :

```
• Set-Location 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client'
• Get-ItemProperty -Path . | Select-Object Version
```

Then depending on the version installed and the OS you're using, you need to uninstall the corresponding KB :

.NET Framework 4.6.1 : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102436

1. Windows 8 ou Windows Server 2012 : KB3102439
2. Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2 : KB3102467
3. Windows 10 : KB3102495

.NET Framework 4.6 : https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/kb/3045560

1. Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 : KB3045562
2. Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2 : KB3045563

Comment: This worked for me. As a side-note I came here while looking for answers to why an installation of SP binaries failed over remote PS. It kept complaining that a pending restart was required. After uninstalling KB3102467 this error also went away. I figure it was simply reporting the wrong error.

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was that I was using Server 2012 R2 and had .Net Framework 4.6 installed.  Apparently SharePoint 2013 installer does not play well if you have that version installed, it's a known issue with MS but they haven't solved it yet https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3087184.

I managed to solve it myself by following this blog post: http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2015/07/28/be-careful-installing-.net-4.6--visual-studio-2015-with.aspx

Essentially by uninstalling a particular Windows Update, KB3045563 to be exact.  I also made sure that any .Net 4.6 specific items in add\remove programs were removed.

Answer (score 2):

Download [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3087184/sharepoint-2013-or-project-server-2013-setup-error-if-the--net-framewo) .zip and extract .dll to SharePoint2013 updates folder and run setup again.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have an older version of .Net 4.5. Try to install the newest one.

http://blogbaris.blogspot.ch/2013/08/sharepoint-2013-installation-endless.html

Answer (score 1):

This issue usually occurs in case you are trying to install The Sharepoint 2013 SP1 on a machine already has .Net framework 4.6, 4.6.1, or 4.6.2 installed.

**Unfortunately,** The SharePoint 2013  is not able to detect the most recent .NET Framework versions, so it reports this issue incorrectly.

---

**Solution**

- **First,** If you are trying to install the SharePoint from DVD drive, Take a copy from the SharePoint Media to a writable location.
- **Second,** Based on the product you are installing, download the corresponding compressed file.

  - [SharePoint Foundation 2013 with Service Pack 1 fix](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/6/2/362c4a9c-4afe-425e-825f-369d34d64f4e/wsssetup_15-0-4709-1000_x64.zip).
  - [SharePoint Server 2013 with Service Pack 1 fix](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/10/27/this-product-requires-microsoft-net-framework-4-5-sharepoint-2013-setup-failed/#comment-6224).
  - [Project Server 2013 with Service Pack 1 fix](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/10/27/this-product-requires-microsoft-net-framework-4-5-sharepoint-2013-setup-failed/#comment-6224).
- **Third,** Extract the .zip file > Copy the .dll file to the Root SharePoint Setup” folder or Updates folder.
- **Forth,** Try now to run the Sharepoint Setup file that should now proceed without any issue.

For more details check [SharePoint 2013 setup unable to proceed: this product requires Microsoft .Net framework 4.5](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/10/27/this-product-requires-microsoft-net-framework-4-5-sharepoint-2013-setup-failed/#comment-6224)

Comment: Thank You! Small fix: use links from here(above are wrong): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3087184/sharepoint-2013-or-project-server-2013-setup-error-if-the-net-framewor

Comment: Thanks, @GennadyG for your valuable note, I have mentioned all links at the solution links at **[SharePoint 2013 setup unable to proceed: this product requires Microsoft .Net framework 4.5](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/this-product-requires-microsoft-net-framework-4-5-sharepoint-2013-setup-failed/)** Have you checked it :)

Comment: Greetings! I'll copy-paste here: SharePoint Foundation 2013 with Service Pack 1 fix:
https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/6/2/362c4a9c-4afe-425e-825f-369d34d64f4e/wsssetup_15-0-4709-1000_x64.zip
SharePoint Server 2013 with Service Pack 1 fix
https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/6/2/362c4a9c-4afe-425e-825f-369d34d64f4e/svrsetup_15-0-4709-1000_x64.zip
Project Server 2013 with Service Pack 1 fix
https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/6/2/362c4a9c-4afe-425e-825f-369d34d64f4e/svrsetup_15-0-4709-1000_x64.zip